# reCaptcha em lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, recaptcha

Olá, estou tentando inserir um recaptcha em uma página, eu consegui com sucesso inserir na página contato através de um formulário em AJAX.

O problema está em um formulário AJAX que esta dentro de um lightbox (No caso uso o featherlight mas acho que isso não influencia), adiciono tudo certinho, porém quando clico em "Não sou um robo" ele fica carregando e retorna o seguinte erro no console:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "www.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at Kp.f.Yb (www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20170411114922/recaptcha__pt_br.js:347:353)
>       at Kp.xb (www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/r20170411114922/recaptcha__pt_br.js:343:59)

Meu código:

1º Formulário:

```
<form action="envia_franquias.php" method="post" id="form_franquias">
    <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo:" required>
    <input type="tel" name="telefone" id="telefone" placeholder="Telefone/Celular:" required>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail:" required>
    <input type="text" name="cidade" id="cidade" placeholder="Cidade:" required>
    <input type="text" name="estado" id="estado" placeholder="UF" required>
    <textarea name="mensagem" id="mensagem" placeholder="Comentários:"></textarea>
    <div id="captcha"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="submit" class="btn_send">
</form>
```

2º Js:

```
    <script>
       var widgetId2;
        var onloadCallback = function() {
            widgetId2 = grecaptcha.render('captcha', {'sitekey' : '6LffYh0UAAAAAA8CJ7p7gmOtc3Cr_gAjqVDTNFYL'});
        };
        $(".btn_franquias a").click(function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                createRecaptcha();
            }, 1000);
        });
        function createRecaptcha() {
            grecaptcha.reset(widgetId2);
        }
    </script>
    <script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit" async defer></script>
```

> Já tentei colocar o script src com o começo http
>
> Já tentei colocar o render em um setTimeOut

Não achei mais nada na internet, alguém poderia de ajudar?